# interfacing vhand 2.0 data glove with mirage arcane head mounted display

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, 3d, augmented-reality

We are doing a project on interaction between various  3D virtual objects using a data glove. The objects are being projected using the mirage arcane head mounted display. We have done the projection part, we now have to do the interaction part. How do we interface the data glove and head mounted display. I am using OpenGL and Visual c++

Comment: Thanx for the response, I have read the manuals and I have done the coding part of the data glove but the head mounted display does not have any api, its basically just GUI. I am confused about how to use both the devices together so that I can interact with the object projected using head mounted display by the data glove. And sorry about the previous questions, I didnot know, I will do it right now :)